# Is there a description of all available wxPython Widgets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using wxPython, (with python 2.7) and am curious as to anyone have provided a sort of guide or an overview over available widgets? When I say a widget I imply a graphical entity drawn on the screen.

I have seen [the documentation of the API](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/frames.html), and by assuming that all "widgets" are sublasses to wx.Window, a better overview can be found in "tree-view in the aforementioned documentation.

However, if I did not know beforehand (from a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/15/wxpython-a-simple-notebook-example/)) what a "notebook" was (in the wx sense), it would have been hard to be inspired to use this widget, using only the API reference.

The [freely available book "wxPython in action"](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irb.hr%2Fusers%2Fmaks%2Fwxact.pdf&ei=aJDTVOq4D5K3oQSs14GoDQ&usg=AFQjCNE3QZs8fON-hBmjKD1zkDihop12vg&bvm=bv.85142067,d.cGU) shows some examples here and there, but does not either contain an overview.

Does a better, more graphical, overview or presentation exist? Not necessarily of all possible widgets, but at least the most popular?

Comment: The documentation for Phoenix (wxPython for Pyhon 3.x), is somwhat better structured and more descriptive, and applies to some extend also to the Python 2.x versions: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/1classindex.html

Comment: Also you may want to look for wxwidgets documentation or guides, as wxPython is mostly wrapper (but has some extensions, which are only in `wx.lib` or something similar).

Comment: wxPython Phoenix works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+

Comment: See [the screenshots page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_screenshots.html) in the manual.

Comment: @VZ I was looking for that. Unfortunately, that shows only a small subset of the widgets available in wxPython. I believe those are the core widgets. There are tons of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Phoenix documentation has screenshots of a lot of the widgets:

- [docs.wxpython.org/gallery.html](http://docs.wxpython.org/gallery.html)

You should also download the wxPython demo. It shows nearly all the widgets and how to use them. It can be found at http://www.wxpython.org

Comment: The link is now broken (2019) - use https://docs.wxpython.org/gallery.html